# Windows Azure throwing DeadLock error when calling async/await from Controller

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

I am only experiencing this error in Azure. I am seeing the following error in the event log:

```
<Event>
   <System>
      <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
      <EventID>1309</EventID>
      <Level>2</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="4:13:44 PM" />
      <EventRecordID>138984609</EventRecordID>
      <Channel>Application</Channel>
      <Computer>***********</Computer>
      <Security />
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data>3005</Data>
      <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
      <Data>12/15/2013 4:13:44 PM</Data>
      <Data>12/15/2013 4:13:44 PM</Data>
      <Data>*****************</Data>
      <Data>134</Data>
      <Data>9</Data>
      <Data>0</Data>
      <Data>/LM/W3SVC/2007260606/ROOT-25-**************</Data>
      <Data>Full</Data>
      <Data>/</Data>
      <Data>C:\DWASFiles\Sites\*******\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\</Data>
      <Data>RD00155D44211F</Data>
      <Data />
      <Data>1788</Data>
      <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
      <Data>IIS APPPOOL\********</Data>
      <Data>InvalidOperationException</Data>
      <Data>An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.</Data>
      <Data>https://*********.azurewebsites.net:443/auth/login</Data>
      <Data>/auth/login</Data>
      <Data>********</Data>
      <Data />
      <Data>False</Data>
      <Data />
      <Data>IIS APPPOOL\******</Data>
      <Data>52</Data>
      <Data>IIS APPPOOL\*******</Data>
      <Data>False</Data>
      <Data />
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

Now I think this is being caused by calling some async code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        var userInputName = await session.Get<string>("UserInputName");
        var userCode = Request[userInputName];
        var getAuthCtxRsp = await someService.GetAuthenticationContext(new UserCodeGetAuthenticationContextRequest
            {
                SessionKey = await sessionResolver.GetSessionKey(),
                UserCode = userCode
            });
        // Some stuff removed here...
        if (getAuthCtxRsp.ChallengeRequired)
        {
            await session.Put("Challenge", getAuthCtxRsp.Challenge, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            await session.Put("NextPage", "/auth/password", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            return new RedirectResult("/auth/challenge/");
        }
        return new RedirectResult("/auth/password");
    }
    // More stuff happens here....

    await session.Put("UserInputName", model.UserInputName, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
    return View(model);
}
```

It seems to be inside the if `(Request.HttpMethod == "POST")` where the error is happening.

This only happens when deployed to Azure. I think it's because it takes longer to reach the session service, than it does on my local machine (but I'm not sure).

I also added an global error handler to the Global.asax but am not seeing anything logged (but I'm not sure if that's because the logging service also uses async methods to send logging statements).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a number of `async` methods that are not following the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so I assume those are methods you wrote yourself. The most likely cause of this error is a wrapper around [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods, probably within your `async` methods.